# Error "Cannot set property 'widthNative'" while loading wasm

Tags: javascript, emscripten, webassembly

I try to stream the output of a wasm in my web canvas.
But, while loading the Main function of my Wasm - the following exception is raised:

```
hello.js:10522 exception thrown: TypeError: Cannot set property 'widthNative' of undefined,TypeError: Cannot set property 'widthNative' of undefined
at Object.updateCanvasDimensions (http://192.168.0.109:8080/hello.js:5876:30)
at Object.setCanvasSize (http://192.168.0.109:8080/hello.js:5854:17)
at _emscripten_set_canvas_size (http://192.168.0.109:8080/hello.js:9590:15)
at wasm-function[764]:168
at wasm-function[1034]:1597
at wasm-function[327]:57
at wasm-function[329]:9
at wasm-function[330]:9
at Object.Module._main (http://192.168.0.109:8080/hello.js:10327:75)
at Object.callMain (http://192.168.0.109:8080/hello.js:10502:30)
```

I've identified the part of the code in the generated js file responsible of the esception:

```
updateCanvasDimensions:function (canvas, wNative, hNative) {
    if (wNative && hNative) {
      canvas.widthNative = wNative;
      canvas.heightNative = hNative;
    } else {
      wNative = canvas.widthNative;
      hNative = canvas.heightNative;
    }
```

I suspect a problem with the compiler emcc.
Here is my compilation command line:

```
emcc -o hello.html hello.c -O3 -s WASM=1 --shell-file html_template/shell_minimal.html -s USE_SDL=2 -s USE_SDL_IMAGE=2 -s NO_EXIT_RUNTIME=1 --embed-file pong.c8 -s EXPORTED_FUNCTIONS=[\"_main\",\"_test_function\"] -s EXTRA_EXPORTED_RUNTIME_METHODS=[\"ccall\"]"
```

Any ideas ? Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.
Actually, it's necessary to assign the property canvas (Module.canvas) before the main script:

```
var Module = {
        canvas: (function() {
            var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
            return canvas;
            })()
    };
```